Six points in a full circular quadrilateral belong to one circle
Today while using the Geogebra program I discovered a new engineering feature, I don't know if it was already known or not

Data: $R$ is a circle with center $O$, $A,B,C,D∈R$, $AD∩BC=E$, $AD∩BC=F$, $R_1$ is the passing circle passing through the points $A,B,E$, its center is $M$, and $R_2$ is the passing circle passing through the points $A,C,D$, its center is $N$, $R_3$ is the passing circle passing through the points $B,C,F$, its center is $P$, and $R_4$ is the passing circle passing through the points $A,D,F$, its center is $Q$, and $R_1∩R_2∩R_3∩R_4=S$.
Required: Prove that the points $M,N,O,P,Q,S$ lie on one circle.
But I don't know how to prove it.
Whoever can help, please kindly
If the feature is already known, please mention a source that talks about it, and thank you

Interesting. First hint I can suggest is to get rid of R3 and R4 as if you prove it for R1 and R2 it will be straightforward then to finish with the circles 3 and 4

It seems that five of them are known to lie on one circle, the rest of the proof that the center of the circle R belongs to the same circle https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Miquel%27s_point

Are you sure there is no additional condition in your case? In the link you gave it seems the center of the initial triangle (called O in your case) would not be cocyclic with the other centers. Maybe BCD isocele?

Fun Fact: $S$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $O$ to line $EF$. Moreover, this perpendicular passes through $AC \cap BD$.

The link i provided talks about 4 points in the general case, while here it talks about 4 points that lie on a circle @Martigan

The first construction I see in such a figure, prior to analysing it, is a complete quadritlateral, giving a hopefuly important keyword for looking whether this property has already been considered elsewhere.

$R_2$ passe through the points $E,C,D$ (change $A$ by $E$)

COMMENT.-The problem can be stated in another equivalent way.
From a point outside the given circle $R$ we draw two lines that determine the points $A,B,C,D$ of the circle which in turn determines the point $E$.
The center $Q$ of $R_4$ is the intersection of the bisectors of the sides $AF$ and $FD$ of the triangle $\triangle{AFD}$ and the center $P$ of $R_3$ is the intersection of the bisectors of the sides $BF$ and $FC$ of the triangle $\triangle{BFC}$.
The points $O,P,Q$ determine an unique circle (which will be the red circle of the statement).
A procedure exactly the same as the one we have just given determines the centers $M$ of $R_1$ and $N$ of $R_2$ and then we can optionally verify that $M$ and $N$ belong to the red circle or see that the equation of the circumcircle of the triangle $\triangle{OMN}$ coincides with the preceding one of the triangle $\triangle{OPQ}$.


WARNING.- The red circle of the statement IS NOT the red circle of the attached figure.
